# freemarker integrated with javascript

Tags: javascript, freemarker

```
<ul id="option5" class="abc">

<#list (optionsSelected)! as options>
<li class=" ${options_index+1}">
   <a href ="${options_url}">
          ${options_description}
   </a>
</li>
</#list>
</ul>


<a href="${content_url}" onClick="abc()"; return false;">


<script>
function abc(){

    $('.nav_header li').click(function () {
           var blah = $(this).children().attr('href');
                etc
                etc ....
                return false;
       }).filter(':first').click();

    }

</script>
```

My output looks like this with the above code:

option1   option2  option3   option4 option5

When I click on option 1 I want to see the "hey I'm option1"
When I click on option 1 I want to see the "hey I'm ur second option"
When I click on option 1 I want to see the "hey whats up I'm 3"
etc without the page reloading.

I want to know how can I get this behavior in freemarkeR? I have my js code for this but how do I put this in freemarkeR? I cannot find good examples of javascript integrated with freemarker. I'm quite new to freemarker,

Answer (score 2):

That is not really freemarker problem, JS doesn't bother about your server side technology.

I would do something like:

```
   <a href ="${options_url}" onClick="alert('${options_description}'); return false;">
          ${options_description}
   </a>
```

So, as you see, tricky part is only to tread your freemarker variable as a correct JS string - using `'` or `"` (where it is allowed).

Comment: hi that worked but that would reload the page right?

Comment: how can I do it without the pae reloading?

Comment: hey thanks that works but since my script is huge I put it in a function inside script tags and then called that function but it does not seem to pick it up. Am I going wrong somewherE? . I have updated my code above. Please tell me whats wrong in it ? And btw thanks for te help

Comment: I mean if I put the laert inside a function and then call the function in onClick then it does not work.

Comment: no in the fiddle you have put in the alert directly inside onClick. I'm putting in a function which includes the alert code inside the onClick

Comment: otherwise it works if I directly put in the alert in the onclick. but does not if i put it in the function and call that function in onlick